# Dumping all files in folder into one and displaying them

Tags: php

I need to take all the files in the folder where the PHP file is, dump them together, and echo them. What is the simplest way to do it?

For example, I have the following files:

**ILikeFish.txt**

```
I like fish please bring me fish!    
Well that's enough don't bring me anymore.
```

**ILikePotatos.js**

```
var Potatos = {yummy:true, amount:5323.6}    
function potatoFunc(stuff) {    
while (stuff=="cool") moreStuff();    
}
```

**Dawgz.png**
*Picture of a dog*

Well, I want the output to be:

*(.txt ignored)*

```
var Potatos = {yummy:true, amount:5323.6}    
function potatoFunc(stuff) {    
while (stuff=="cool") moreStuff();    
}
```

*(Picture ignored)*

How can I do it? Thanks for answering!

Also, I'm VERY basic in PHP and I know nothing, so please forgive me if this question is super dumb. Also, I AM aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408423/is-using-php-to-collate-multiple-javascript-files-going-to-be-faster-than-includ) question, but it doesn't answer how to do it!

Also, my final goal is to include all my libraries and comments using one line of

```
<script src="http://MySite/AllJsses.php"></script>
```

And again, ***Thanks for taking the time and answering!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after playing a little with google, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) and my genius brain I came up with the following:

```
<?php
$files = glob("*.js");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
echo file_get_contents($files[$i]);
}
?>
```

Thanks to myself and to some guy on other forums for answering this question! :D

Also, if any of you find any errors / performance issues / anything, please comment, because otherwise host gonna kill me. Thank you!

Comment: @u_mulder Gonna update the code in like 3 seconds to something another person suggested. Stay tuned! :D